# Javascript is not accepting JSON data as variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to connect to an API to display some data on my website.

I've already defined `Http` as `new XMLHttpRequest();`, and `url` as the API endpoint.

Here's the code:

```js
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
      var api = JSON.stringify(Http.responseText)
      document.getElementById("stat").innerHTML = "Powering over " + api.total_bandwidth.TB + "TB of private internet traffic"
}
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: api.total_bandwidth is undefined

What is wrong here? Is `Http.responseText` already an Object? Did I define the API wrong?

This is the response of `api`:

```
{"total_bandwidth": {"GB": 110842.05, "TB": 108.24, "PB": 0.11}}
```

Comment: I think you meant to use `JSON.parse` rather than `JSON.stringify`...

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're stringifying the object (response), then trying to get "TB" from a string.

Try parsing `api` then getting the properties from it:

```
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    var api = JSON.stringify(Http.responseText);
    var apiJson = JSON.parse(api);
    document.getElementById("stat").innerHTML = "Powering over " + apiJson.total_bandwidth.TB + "TB of private internet traffic";
};
```

Edit: Turns out that "JSON.stringify" was actually a mistake.

> I think you meant to use JSON.parse rather than JSON.stringify... - Robin Zigmond

I think you meant `JSON.parse` (to PARSE the response text) instead of `JSON.stringify`:

```
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
      var api = JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
      document.getElementById("stat").innerHTML = "Powering over " + api.total_bandwidth.TB + "TB of private internet traffic"
}
```

*Learn more about `JSON.parse` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse*